# Cannot POST to /path despite post method available

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have the following code for my login page

```
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("./public/login.html");
});
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

When I press the login button on login.html, which sends a post request to the server, I get the error `Cannot POST /login.html`. When I was looking at this I thought it might be because it is posting to  the address /login.html instead of just /login. Is this the problem? If so, how do I make the login.html code display at localhost:3000/login instead of localhost:3000/login.html?

EDIT:

The HTML that calls the api:

```
<div class='body' id='b'>
                <form method='POST' action="http://localhost:3000/login">
                    <input type='text' id='top' placeholder="username">
                    <input type='email' placeholder='email'>
                    <input type='password' placeholder='password'>
                    <input type='password' placeholder='repeat password'>
                    <br>
                    <button type='submit'>go!</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: You need to show the code where you call the route

Comment: The HTML? I will add it to the bottom of the question

Comment: could you try sending the post request from postman?